# How to insert where in trigger

Tags: mysql

MySQL Trigger what problem here.
I need to insert value with where in Trigger

```
BEGIN
INSERT INTO expenses(Cost, Pay, Date, StudentID)    
SELECT 0, 0, CURRENT_DATE, UID
    FROM users
    WHERE GroupID = 10;
END
```

[image: Error Image]

[image: Error Image2]

Comment: What's the problem? Doesnt it work? is there a error?

Comment: yes got an error in this code I need to insert where in my code insert can you tell me how? this code doesn't work :(

Comment: Share the complete trigger code including CREATE TRIGGER statement and also share the error message... edit your post

Comment: didn't read the error before i've posted but the error tells me there should already be a trigger for table users with ALTER INSERT TRIGGER... check the information_schema.TRIGGERS table

Comment: I delete this trigger but I got same error

Comment: Maybe there's another trigger on the `users` table.

Comment: solved thank you guys